# installing an msu update package on windows 7 while windows update service is disabled

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Iam trying to install an msu update package on my corporate's PCs, but when executing the msu it fails with the following error:

[windows update standalone installer
installer encountered an error: 0x80070422
the serice cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.]

I've contacted my network administrator and he said that we can't enable windows update on the PCs due to some problems.

so is there any way to install the msu package without enabling the windows update service such as getting the package as exe file?

any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than disabling the update client, your admin could achieve the same result by enforcing the NoAutoUpdate policy setting. This way the clients will not check in and install updates when available. You should still be able to manually apply updates as the service will still be running.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010